# swift scenekit class gameviewconroller has no initilizer

Tags: swift, scenekit

i was following a tutorial exactly and when the tutorial says to run the program i get an error, "class gameviewcontroller has no initalizers"

I copied it down exactly so i dont know what is wrong but i think it might be when i retrive the nodes.

```
var cameraNode: SCNNode
var shelfNode: SCNNode
var baseCanNode: SCNNode

func createScene(){

cameraNode = levelScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "camera", recursively: true)!
shelfNode = levelScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "shelf", recursively: true)!

guard let canScene = SCNScene(named: "resources.scnassets/Can.scn") else { return }
baseCanNode = canScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "can", recursively: true)!
}
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Thank You.

Comment: Show the class name and its super class name.

Comment: the class name is GameViewController the super class is UIViewcontroller i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add exclamation points to the end

```
var cameraNode: SCNNode!
var shelfNode: SCNNode!
var baseCanNode: SCNNode!
```

instead of

```
var cameraNode: SCNNode
var shelfNode: SCNNode
var baseCanNode: SCNNode
```